# How can i Convert json to csv in python

Tags: python, json, csv

How can I convert the following `json` format logs to `csv` file in `python`:
Json Input (`log.json`):

```
{"time":"14472","abc":"0","Def":[{"name":"C","value":77},{"name":"N","value":88}]}  
{"time":"1447","abc":"1","Def":[{"name":"C","value":99,{"name":"N","value":0.12}]}
```

Csv Output:

```
time   abc    name   value  
14472   0      C      77  
14472   0      N      88  
1447    1      C     99    
1447    1      N      0.12
```

Comment: Are you sure you got the output right? Don't you mean `N 88` in the 2nd line and `C 99` in the 3rd?

Comment: You are going to have to have valid json first as well. I recommend [jsonlint](http://jsonlint.com/) for checking that.

Comment: Did you try something by yourself, if so please tell us where you got stuck, or are you just waiting for someone to post the answer?

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at https://docs.python.org/2/library/json.html

I haven't used it personally but I skimmed the docs once and it seems that it creates a dictionary for each json object and a list for each array.

Once you have that then you can get the keys for the column labels and then you can it shouldn't be a big deal to actually write the file.

Answer (score 0):

This should work assuming the 'log.json' input file contains valid json objects:

```
import csv
import json

with open('log.json', 'rb') as infile, open('output.csv', 'wb') as outfile:
    fieldnames = ['time', 'abc', 'name', 'value']
    writer = csv.DictWriter(outfile, fieldnames, delimiter='\t')
    writer.writeheader()
    for line in infile:
        row = json.loads(line)
        for a_def in row['Def']:
            writer.writerow({'time': row['time'],
                             'abc': row['abc'],
                             'name': a_def['name'],
                             'value': a_def['value']})
```